# jest snapshot formats the moment object each time instead of returning the moment object

Tags: javascript, jestjs, momentjs, moment-timezone

I have a Jest test that formats an array via `map()` which sets a `startDate`.  I am capturing the snapshot of the returned map because it's fragile business logic.  However, the snapshot logic appears to be modifying the value of the object.  Codesandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/moment-tz-test-xv1wr?file=/src/index.test.js

The returned value tests correct that the value is a moment object:

```
    expect(moment.isMoment(events[0].startDate)).toBe(true);
```

But the snapshot converted is this:

```
Object {
    "endDate": "2021-02-18T17:09:16.582Z",
    "id": undefined,
    "startDate": "2021-02-18T17:09:16.582Z",
  },
```

Is there a way to prevent the snapshot from converting the value to a string?

Answer (score 0):

You may consider instead testing it like this. It will ensure that the resulting array has 5 items and each of them is an object and `startDate` and `endDate` are instances of moment

```
expect(events).toHaveLength(5);
expect(events).toEqual(
  expect.arrayContaining([
    {
      endDate: expect.any(moment),
      id: undefined,
      startDate: expect.any(moment)
    }
  ])
);
```

Comment: i will look into this.